# Custom XML Formatter add only required namespaces

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces, xmlserializer

I'm having to add namespace prefixes to XML generated by some of my api end points due to the client application using xpaths with hardcoded prefixes (dont get me started).

I've successfully created a custom XmlSerializerOutputFormatter that overrides the `Serialize` method as follows:

```
    public class CustomXmlOutputFormatter : XmlSerializerOutputFormatter
    {
        protected override void Serialize(XmlSerializer xmlSerializer, XmlWriter xmlWriter, object value)
        {
            var namespaces = new XmlQualifiedName[]
            {
                new XmlQualifiedName("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                new XmlQualifiedName("t1", "my.namespace.one"),
                new XmlQualifiedName("t2", "my.namespace.two"),
                new XmlQualifiedName("t3", "my.namespace.three"),

            };

            var nsManager = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(namespaces);                        
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value, nsManager);
        }
    }
```

And this works insofar as the XML is produced using the correct namespace prefix.

However, I'm now getting all my namespace prefixes in every XML generated, even if they aren't used.
For example, the xml below only uses items from the "t1" namespace, but as I've declared all three in the namespace manager, I get all three out in the xml:

```
<t1:MyRootNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:t1="my.namespace.one" 
            xmlns:t2="my.namespace.two" 
            xmlns:t3="my.namespace.three">
    <t1:Hello>World</t1:Hello>
</t1:MyRootNode>
```

This is significantly increasing the size of the XML, as we have over 200 different namespaces that **COULD** be used in total - but each end point actually uses only two or three different namespaces max.

What I'm looking for is a way to only include the namespaces that are actually used by the object being serialized (or any of its child objects).

As all my objects are annotated with the relevent XML serialization attributes (such as `[XmlElement]`) and they use the namespace parameter where required, I guess I could write some horrible reflection to go down the rabbithole and find any namespaces in use that way.

However, I'm hoping there's a far more elegant (and probably more obvious) solution that I cannot see :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up implementing this using reflection:

```
    protected override void Serialize(XmlSerializer xmlSerializer, XmlWriter xmlWriter, object value)
    {
        //this is a List<XmlQualifiedName>() that contains all the namespaces and prefixes we could be using - its dynamically built during the constructor from a json file for ease of use.
        var allNamespaces = AllPossibleNamespaces.ToList(); //create a temp copy we can modify

        //remove surplus namespaces
        var usedNamespaces = GetUsedNamespaces(value.GetType());
        allNamespaces.RemoveAll(n => !usedNamespaces.Contains(n.Namespace));

        //now add in the default ones we always want
        allNamespaces.AddRange(requiredNamespaces);

        //finally, serialize the object using the namespaces and prefixes
        var nsManager = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(allNamespaces.ToArray());
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value,nsManager);            
    }

    private List<string> GetUsedNamespaces(Type baseType)
    {
        var usedNamespaces = new List<string>();

        var attribs = baseType.GetXmlAttributes();
        baseType.GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(p => attribs.AddRange(p.GetXmlAttributes()));

        foreach (var a in attribs)
        {
            var nsProp = a.GetType().GetProperty("Namespace",typeof(string));
            if (nsProp!=null)
            {
                var ns = (string)nsProp.GetValue(a);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ns) && !usedNamespaces.Contains(ns))
                    usedNamespaces.Add(ns);
            }
        }

        foreach(var child in baseType.GetProperties())
        {
            var propType = child.PropertyType;
            var type = propType;
            if (propType.IsClass)
            {
                //dont check inside strings :)
                if (propType != typeof(string))
                {
                    foreach (var iface in propType.GetInterfaces())
                    {
                        if (iface.IsGenericType && iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
                        {
                            type = propType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                        }
                    }
                    GetUsedNamespaces(type).ForEach(n => { 
                        if (!usedNamespaces.Contains(n)) 
                            usedNamespaces.Add(n);
                    });                        
                }
            }                
        }

        return usedNamespaces;
    }
```

If a better solution without the need for chained reflection appears, I'll give that the accepted answer, as I would have preferred not do have to do this :)